# How to create a 2 column grid with square shaped cells in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, lazyvgrid

I'm trying to replicate this UI in SwiftUI using a Grid.

[image]

I created the cell like this.

```
struct MenuButton: View {
    let title: String
    let icon: Image
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print(#function)
        }) {
            VStack {
                icon
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                Text(title)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 160, height: 160)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.fr_primary, lineWidth: 0.6))
    }
}
```

And the Grid like so.

```
struct LoginUserTypeView: View {
    private let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 20)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 30) {
                ForEach(Menu.UserType.allCases, id: \.self) { item in
                    MenuButton(title: item.description, icon: Image(item.icon))
                }
            }
            
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

But on smaller screens like the iPod, the cells are overlapped.

[image]

On bigger iPhone screens, still the spacing is not correct.

[image]

What adjustments do I have to make so that in every screen size, the cells would show in a proper square shape and equal spacing on all sides?

Comment: Does this your questions answered? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65890000/14733292

Comment: @RajaKishan Thanks. I gave it a try. It also works but I don't want to hardcode the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

`MenuButton` has fixed width and height, thats why it behaves incorrectly.

---

You could utilise `.aspectRatio` and `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` for this:

```
struct MenuButton: View {
    let title: String
    let icon: Image

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print(#function)
        }) {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                icon
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 60, maxHeight: 60)
                Text(title)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color. fr_primary, lineWidth: 0.6))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That indeed fixed my cell sizing issue. However there's a small problem. Even though the cell resizes, the content inside (image and the text) are still the same size. So in smaller screens, it looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/8OpxPYI.png). Is there a way to resize those elements to fit inside the cell as well?

Comment: I tried setting the aspect ratio to the `Text` object. [It's pushing out the image.](https://i.imgur.com/4IKQjXO.png)

Comment: @Isuru I assume you want to keep your buttons square.